# PermissionError: [Error13] write access in directory using python flask and wsgi

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I'm getting a

```py
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles'
```

when I try to write a csv file in the uploadfiles folder using python/flask after configuring the wsgi. everything works as it should when I run from the development side so I know there is NO errors in my code.
This is the flask code

```py
@app.route('/write', methods =['GET','POST'])
def checked():
    if request.method =='POST':
        with open('/var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles/test.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(["this", "is", "a", "test"])
    return "uploaded"
```

In the httpd.conf file

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName *ip*
     ErrorLog /path/
     WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in the app.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

When I tried adding a second  for the uploadfiles folder in app.conf, it threw an httpd.service error at me so that's why I didn't include it in here.

Comment: It is going to relate to Unix file permissions rather than apache config. Check ownership and permissions on the directory itself, and also on any parent directories in the path to it.

Comment: @alani how can I change the permissions for a folder? It is drwxrwxr-x or will I need to contact the admin?

Comment: That depends whether you own it or somebody else does. If you own it then you could just make it world-writable (`chmod 777 /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles`) -- but otherwise it is probably going to need root access to sort out.  (I'm guessing here that you are not a member of the same groups as the apache user.)

Comment: I just changed permissions so the directories(including parent) it needs to go through are now drwxrwxrwx  but I'm still getting the same issue. Just tried your command. Unfortunately same issue persists.

Comment: *One* of the leading directories must have a permissions issue. You might want to do `ls -ld / /var/www /var/www/python /var/www/python/flaskapp /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles` and look at them all. Note: do not make them all writable: only the last of them needs to be writable. But the web user will need at least `x` on all of the ones leading to it.

Comment: Just checked it. Everything inside of /var/www/python, so from flaskapp/ (but not including python/ ) has drwxrwxrwx . The three directories before flaskapp have drwxr-xr-x. It seems I can upload files to the folder now(separate functionality) but I can't create a csv and place it.

Comment: Can you please update the question to show the full stack trace with the error message, so we can see exactly which line of code is generating it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the traceback due to sensitve information. i can tell you that it is the "with open('/var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles/test.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:" which is causing it.

Comment: For some of them it has the "drwxrwxrwx apache apache ... "while others have "drwxrwxrwx myusername myusername". I can write to the folders that have "apache" instead of "myusername" so how would I change it?

Comment: Only root can `chown` a directory (change ownership), but it shouldn't matter who owns the directory if the permissions are the same for all users (as is the case with drwxrwxrwx).

Comment: I'm kind of stumped now, because I can't see an obvious permissions problem, and anyway I am surprised that the error message references the directory rather than the csv file itself. Hopefully someone else will have an idea.

Comment: I just tried  "chown -R apache /var/www/python/flaskapp/flaskapp/uploadfiles" and it seemed to have done the trick. I guess it was dependent on the owner of the directory

Comment: Glad it worked, although given that you said that everything below /var/www/python is drwxrwxrwx, I don't understand why it wasn't working already.